# How do I omit result in missing props?

Tags: typescript

given a base type define

```
interface Base {
  base: boolean
}

interface AFromBase extends Base {
  propA: number
}

interface BFromBase extends Base {
  propB: number[]
}

type Final = AFromBase | BFromBase
```

This will result in an error:

> Type '{ custom: false; propA: number; }' is not assignable to type
> 'Custom'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and
> 'propA' does not exist in type 'Custom'.ts(2322)

```
type Custom = Omit<Final, 'base'> & {
  custom: boolean,
}

const instance: Custom = {
  custom: false,
  propA: 123,
  ~~~~~~~~~~
}
```

But this works

```
type Custom = (Omit<AFromBase, 'base'> | Omit<BFromBase, 'base'>) & {
  custom: boolean,
}

const instance: Custom = {
  custom: false,
  propA: 123,
}
```

Could anyone please explain to me why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union type behaves like XOR. So, if you want to see the keys of `Final`

```ts
type Final = AFromBase | BFromBase

type keysOfFinal = keyof Final;
// returns type keysOfFinal = "base"
```

Let's add a common property that's not in the `Base`

```ts
interface Base {
  base: boolean
}

interface AFromBase extends Base {
  common: number;
  propA: number
}

interface BFromBase extends Base {
  common: number;
  propB: number[]
}

type Final = AFromBase | BFromBase

type keysOfFinal = keyof Final;
// returns type keysOfFinal = "common" | "base"
```

So, `Omit` with `Final` type does not behave like you would expect from a type that represents type `AFromBase` or type `BFromBase`, which is what common sense says. And hence you see the error you mentioned. And that's why you have to `Omit` individually and then use it in Union.

TS Playground link: https://tsplay.dev/WYJOzw

Here is an example of union with common fields: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#unions-with-common-fields

I could not find the same example in the latest documentation, but this example shows the dilemma. I am pasting the code below for posterity:

```ts
interface Bird {
  fly(): void;
  layEggs(): void;
}

interface Fish {
  swim(): void;
  layEggs(): void;
}

declare function getSmallPet(): Fish | Bird;

let pet = getSmallPet();
pet.layEggs();

// Only available in one of the two possible types
pet.swim();
Property 'swim' does not exist on type 'Bird | Fish'.
  Property 'swim' does not exist on type 'Bird'.
```

> Union types can be a bit tricky here, but it just takes a bit of intuition to get used to. If a value has the type A | B, we only know for certain that it has members that both A and B have. In this example, Bird has a member named fly. We can’t be sure whether a variable typed as Bird | Fish has a fly method. If the variable is really a Fish at runtime, then calling pet.fly() will fail.